# JSReports: unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, jsonparser, jsreport

This may require someone familiar with JSReports, but ideas from others are welcome...

I know the "unexpected token < in JSON at position 0" is typically an indication of an HTML formatted string being sent to JSON.parse(), so I've done debugging to ensure the object that I THINK I'm passing into the JSReports rendering engine is valid JSON, but I'm not sure that's what it's getting stuck on.

Script file (content.js):

```js
// server side script fetching remote data and preparing report data source
const request = require('request');

// call remote http rest api
async function fetchCircleIn() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const options = {
        url: 'http://localhost:5000/API/Meets/14/Events?ForCircleIn=true',
        method: 'GET',
        json:true };

        request(options,
        function(error, response, body) {
            if(error){
                console.log(error);
                reject(error);
            }
            else{
                console.log(body);
                resolve(body);
            }
        });
    })
}

// add jsreport hook which modifies the report input data
async function beforeRender(req, res) {
    let data = await fetchCircleIn();
    console.log(data);
    req.data.Individuals = data;
}
```

Here's an abridged version of that response:

```
[
{
    "IndividualId": 6,
    "FirstName": "Jeff",
    "NickName": null,
    "LastName": "Moore",
    "Age": 35,
    "IsTeamCaptain": false,
    "Events": [
        {
            "EventId": 18,
            "EventDescription": "Progressive Freestyle Relay",
            "EventNumber": "5",
            "DistanceNum": 250,
            "ScheduleTime": "10:00:00-05",
            "AgeMin": 0,
            "AgeMax": 99,
            "CreatedDtm": "2021-06-02T03:18:06.591Z",
            "MeetId": 14
        },
        {
            "EventId": 11,
            "EventDescription": "Watermelon Relay Race",
            "EventNumber": "8",
            "DistanceNum": 100,
            "ScheduleTime": "11:00:00-05",
            "AgeMin": 0,
            "AgeMax": 99,
            "CreatedDtm": "2021-06-02T03:10:53.180Z",
            "MeetId": 14
        },
        {
            "EventId": 22,
            "EventDescription": "Decades Relay Race",
            "EventNumber": "13",
            "DistanceNum": 25,
            "ScheduleTime": null,
            "AgeMin": 21,
            "AgeMax": 99,
            "CreatedDtm": "2021-06-02T03:20:30.427Z",
            "MeetId": 14
        }
    ]
},
{
    "IndividualId": 1,
    "FirstName": "Mark",
    "NickName": null,
    "LastName": "Rodenhauser",
    "Age": 41,
    "IsTeamCaptain": null,
    "Events": [
        {
            "EventId": 10,
            "EventDescription": "Corkscrew Individual Race",
            "EventNumber": "6",
            "DistanceNum": 25,
            "ScheduleTime": "10:30:00-05",
            "AgeMin": 0,
            "AgeMax": 99,
            "CreatedDtm": "2021-06-02T03:09:47.269Z",
            "MeetId": 14
        },
        {
            "EventId": 1,
            "EventDescription": "Doggie Paddle",
            "EventNumber": "11",
            "DistanceNum": 25,
            "ScheduleTime": null,
            "AgeMin": 0,
            "AgeMax": 99,
            "CreatedDtm": "2022-06-28T03:31:55.892Z",
            "MeetId": 14
        },
        {
            "EventId": 14,
            "EventDescription": "Dragon Fly Individual Race",
            "EventNumber": "12",
            "DistanceNum": 25,
            "ScheduleTime": null,
            "AgeMin": 21,
            "AgeMax": 99,
            "CreatedDtm": "2021-06-02T03:14:37.616Z",
            "MeetId": 14
        }
    ]
},
{
    "IndividualId": 2,
    "FirstName": "Britt",
    "NickName": null,
    "LastName": "Sensat",
    "Age": 43,
    "IsTeamCaptain": true,
    "Events": [
        {
            "EventId": 18,
            "EventDescription": "Progressive Freestyle Relay",
            "EventNumber": "5",
            "DistanceNum": 250,
            "ScheduleTime": "10:00:00-05",
            "AgeMin": 0,
            "AgeMax": 99,
            "CreatedDtm": "2021-06-02T03:18:06.591Z",
            "MeetId": 14
        },
        {
            "EventId": 11,
            "EventDescription": "Watermelon Relay Race",
            "EventNumber": "8",
            "DistanceNum": 100,
            "ScheduleTime": "11:00:00-05",
            "AgeMin": 0,
            "AgeMax": 99,
            "CreatedDtm": "2021-06-02T03:10:53.180Z",
            "MeetId": 14
        },
        {
            "EventId": 1,
            "EventDescription": "Doggie Paddle",
            "EventNumber": "11",
            "DistanceNum": 25,
            "ScheduleTime": null,
            "AgeMin": 0,
            "AgeMax": 99,
            "CreatedDtm": "2022-06-28T03:31:55.892Z",
            "MeetId": 14
        },
        {
            "EventId": 22,
            "EventDescription": "Decades Relay Race",
            "EventNumber": "13",
            "DistanceNum": 25,
            "ScheduleTime": null,
            "AgeMin": 21,
            "AgeMax": 99,
            "CreatedDtm": "2021-06-02T03:20:30.427Z",
            "MeetId": 14
        }
    ]
}
]
```

Console output running JSReports locally:

```
*Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
2022-07-07T13:21:41.411Z - debug: Replaced assets ["circle-in-styles.css"]
2022-07-07T13:21:41.413Z - debug: Rendering engine handlebars using dedicated-process strategy
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:52364/cde5a262-592c-4ca2-abaf-90582f0ffd4b
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Debugger attached.
Waiting for2022-07-07T13:21:41.699Z - warn: Rendering request 2 finished with error in 2306 ms
 the 2022-07-07T13:21:41.700Z - warn: Error when processing render request 2 Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\mark.rodenhauser\Repos\GitHub\Lakewood-Lightning-Funmeet-Reporting\node_modules\jsreport-core\lib\render\resolveReferences.js:4:17)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\mark.rodenhauser\Repos\GitHub\Lakewood-Lightning-Funmeet-Reporting\node_modules\jsreport-core\lib\render\engineScript.js:35:17)
    at process.<anonymous> (C:\Users\mark.rodenhauser\Repos\GitHub\Lakewood-Lightning-Funmeet-Reporting\node_modules\script-manager\lib\worker-processes.js:66:36)
    at process.emit (node:events:520:28)
    at emit (node:internal/child_process:938:14)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:84:21)
debugger to disconnect...
2022-07-07T13:21:41.702Z - warn: Error during processing request at http://localhost:5488/api/report/Circle-In
*
```

Comment: "so I've done debugging to ensure the object that I THINK I'm passing into the JSReports rendering engine is valid JSON" — Have you examined the response in the Network tab?

Comment: Please read [the documentation for `request`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request); in particular the part where it was marked DO NOT USE two and a half years ago.

Comment: there is a possibility your sever is not sending the data as json, but as text. Click on network tab, and see the preview. You should be able to expand the array of objects. If not that's the issue

Comment: FYI, versions of Node > 8 have a method [`util.promisify`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#utilpromisifyoriginal) which will do the wrapping of the callback for you.

Comment: Thanks all I'm picking up this project I'm doing for hobby/volunteer/charity after a year off and stuff's just not working as it was so I'm figuring out what's changed. @Quentin is right that I should have already looked at the network tab, because doing so has highlighted that the issue is not related to my API response at all; JSReports is having issues looking up the template I believe...just a terrible error handling in the product if you ask me. 

I'm going to close this, get latest JSReports, and re-implement the (2) reports, as well as refactor away from 'request' package. thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Thanks all I'm picking up this project I'm doing for hobby/volunteer/charity after a year off and stuff's just not working as it was so I'm figuring out what's changed. @Quentin is right that I should have already looked at the network tab, because doing so has highlighted that the issue is not related to my API response at all; JSReports is having issues looking up the template I believe...just a terrible error handling in the product if you ask me. I'm going to close this, get latest JSReports, and re-implement the (2) reports, as well as refactor away from 'request' package. thanks! –
G